# How does Jenkins store user passwords

Tags: jenkins

On Jenkins, the file (such as) `/var/jenkins_home/users/admin_7771455809280338965/config.xml` contains user information for admin, including the user's password.

On previous Jenkins versions (a few years ago), one could reset the password using a technique described at [How to Reset Forgotten Jenkins Admin User's Password, Aug. 8, 2018, LearnITGuide.net](https://www.learnitguide.net/2018/08/reset-jenkins-admin-users-password.html): essentially:

```
SALT=hello
PASS=princess
echo -n "$PASS{$SALT}" | sha256sum | sed 's/[ -]//g'
d39399b5853756683fe982f3e03bc0010b7efaf74233f39971790fd96aa45f8b
```

Then one could put `hello: d39399b5853756683fe982f3e03bc0010b7efaf74233f39971790fd96aa45f8b` in the `<passwordHash>...</passwordHash>` section of `/var/jenkins_home/users/admin_7771455809280338965/config.xml`

Then, restarting Jenkins, or restarting the Docker container which contains Jenkins, would make the new password for admin be, in this case, "princess".

This has stopped working at some point in the previous years, not sure why.

How does Jenkins determine if a user's password is valid or not?

(I am not interested in alternate techniques to reset Jenkins password, I know there are many; I am trying to understand how Jenkins determines if a user's password is valid.)